# Client Host Rejected, Access denied error while sending smtp mails

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp

I am trying to send mail outside my network and this is the error I am getting, and I know this is an error of relaying.
I need to know a proper solution so that sending mail can be possible.
I am trying this code:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = smtp....com;
client.Port = 25;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sEmailID, sPassword);
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it by doing `client.UsedefaultCredentials=false` before assigning the Credentials.

Comment: I solved the same by specifying the details in the web config. And changing the host by specifying the IP of the host. And that worked.

Comment: +1: for the answer as this might solve someone's problem as well. Thanks buddy for replying at least. Most important question but very less know the reason. :)